# How to generate soft lockup in preemptive kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, scheduling, panic

I have enabled `CONFIG_BOOTPARAM_SOFTLOCKUP_PANIC` in kernel configuration, now I want to test this behavior that kernel should panic in case of softlockup,

To try this I have created one module,

```
int thread_function(void *data)
{
    int var;
    var = 10;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Inside %s %s\n",STR_MOD,__func__);
    //while(!kthread_should_stop()){
        while(1) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Mutiplying...\n");
            var = var*var*var; //test
        }
    //}

    return var;
}

static int kernel_init(void)
{
    data = 20;
    printk(KERN_INFO"insmod %s\n",STR_MOD);
    /*task = kthread_create(&thread_function,(void *)data,"SD");*/
    task = kthread_run(&thread_function,(void *)data,"SD");
    set_cpus_allowed(task, *cpumask_of(0));
    printk(KERN_INFO"Kernel Thread : %s\n",task->comm);
    return 0;
}
```

With this CPU 0 is busy processing task and reports ~99.9% usage with `top`

but it is not generating softlockup.

So, my question is how can I achieve this?

Comment: Try busy-wait inside spinlock critical section. One purpose of soft lockup detector is to found long-run spinlock critical sections.

Comment: Usually CPU is held for long time like 11 secs by single process, this softlockup issue will occurs.

Comment: github: [softlockup_test](https://github.com/saiyamd/softlockup_test)